# Remembering image position on upload inside v-for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am having a hard time figuring this one out.

I'm using Vue.js and I'm trying to create some sort of a dashboard where a user would be able to upload up to five images of visitors that are allowed to use some service that said user is providing.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="row" v-for="(n, i) in 5" :key="n">
  <div :id="'popover' + visitor.id + '-' + i" variant="primary">
    <div class="card visitor-image">
      <b-popover :target="'popover' + visitor.id + '-' + i" triggers="click focus">
        <template slot="title">Edit image</template>
        <button
          v-if="checkImage(i)"
          class="btn btn-danger image-btns"
          @click="deleteImage(visitor.id, visitor.Photos[i].id)"
        >Delete</button>
        <p
          v-if="uploadProgress < 100 && uploadProgress > 0"
          class="progress-text"
        >Upload progress: {{ uploadProgress }}%</p>
        <label
          v-if="!checkImage(i)"
          :for="'image-input' + visitor.id + '-' + i"
          class="btn btn-primary image-btns"
        >Upload</label>
        <input
          class="profile-image"
          :id="'image-input' + visitor.id + '-' + i"
          type="file"
          :ref="'fileInput' + visitor.id + '-' + i"
          style="display: none"
          accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"
          placeholder="Upload"
          @change="selectFile($event, visitor.id, 'fileInput' + visitor.id + '-' + i)"
        >
      </b-popover>
      <img
        class="card-img-top profile-image"
        v-if="checkImage(i)"
        :src="getImage(i)"
        :id="visitor.Photos[i].id"
      >
      <img class="card-img-top avatar-image" v-else src="../assets/avatar.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

None of the functions are important here, the only thing that matters is this "v-for" loop I'm using.
As you can see, I'm iterating through all the visitors and their images and I'm binding a key for each one.

What I want to know is, how do I use that key so that once I click on one of the avatar images and upload a photo, that same photo is upload in that exact div?
Right now, wherever I click one of the five divs to upload an image, it will be displayed on the first div even if I click on the last div in the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the codepen for file upload inside the `v-for` loop. I have used splice for adding an image at a particular index. Please refer the following codepen for more detail.

codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGYoyr